# Google maps: get real width/height

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api to insert a map in my page and inside of it I insert a rectangle. Everything works fine but I have this question: if the users zooms in or zooms out, I would like to "capture" the real width/height of the map (latitude/longitude left top  and   latitude/longitude bottom right) so I can select the points in my database that should be inside the viewport of the map.

I can easily select from my databas all the points that are inside a well defined rectangle, so how do I know the real with/height of the map that is being displayed (considering always the zoom applied)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looking for `width` and `height`, you're looking to get the bounds of the map which, conveniently enough is available via the `[getBounds][1]` method on the `map` object.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle',function() {
   //make some ajax request with map.getBounds()
});
```

Every time the user moves the map (pans/zooms) you can use the `getBounds()` method to get the lat/lng at the corners of the map.